# how to pass php var into javascript

Tags: javascript, php, sql, database

So i have a question that might seems easy to fix some some of you guys, but i can't seem to do it. I have a PHP file with this inside:

```
$bang .= "<td><a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?id=".$row['userId']."'>test</a></td>";
$bang .= "<td><i class=\"fas fa-cog\" onclick='getandupdateuser();'></i></td>";
```

now i want to use the `$row['userId]` in the `getandupdateuser()` function below.
problem is, i cant pass the userid into some script to var it first and then use it. since its in a while loop. and i need it to work for multiple `$bang` items.

so how do i pass my `$row` result into the script below?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: I've tried ugly ass things like this: `getandupdateuser($row['userId'])`

Comment: and also searched SO but can't seem to find a fix for this

Comment: When you call your javascript function? on click of particular row ?

Comment: yes, its onclick, and then it should pass the value from only that specific row

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
$bang .= "<td><i class=\"fas fa-cog\" onclick='getandupdateuser();'></i></td>";
```

to

```
$bang .= "<td><i class=\"fas fa-cog\" onclick='getandupdateuser(" . $row['userId'] . ");'></i></td>";
```

Comment: ^ this worked, ty :P